# Increasing slow laptop speed with new hard drive

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, laptop, speed, toshiba-laptop

I have a toshiba windows 10 laptop, that initially had Windows 7 installed on it. It has 6GB of RAM and an Intel Core i5-3210m CPU. The hard disk inside is a 2012 750GB 5400 rpm hard drive, that works at 3Gb/s.

Now since a year or 2, I noticed this laptop runs significantly slow. Under regular basic task:watching streaming videos, watching a movie, even web browsing, even only opening a folder takes a anormally long time.

I checked the ressource usage; RAM isnt the problem, neither is the CPU. However, the hard disk seems to often be running at 100% in the windows ressource management.

This laptop is clean and has no virus or malwares that could slow it down whatsoever either.

However I also noticed that under basic task, the fan seems to be spinning a lot, and letting lot of hot air out the vent on the side. Also, general temperature(CPU, gpu,..) seems to be a little high even under basic task.

So my question is, would swapping the hard drive to a 1TB 2015 one, with 6Gb/s instead of 3 could help make this laptop be "faster"? Or it is useless? Could the potential "overheating" of this laptop be the cause of it being slow?

Thank you!

Comment: I think you need to find the cause of the 100% disk IO utilisation - that isn't normal.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick but could it be because its 3Gb/s and just saturate the disk IO fast under few basic tasks at the same time?